# Emberjs: findAll method missing on store

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to get emberjs working on rails and have been following this tutorial:

http://www.zhubert.com/blog/2012/04/28/ember-dot-js-and-rails-part-2/

When I try to run this command in the browser console:

```
var posts = App.store.findAll(App.Post)
```

I get an error because there is no findAll method on the store. I am using ember-data and am setting up the store like this:

```
App.store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 4,
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create()
});
```

I've been using the ember rails generators but the whole thing seems pretty flakey, please help!

Comment: I was following the same tutorial, and it turned out that I just had to use `App.Post.all()` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using Ember's new router, it expects you to provide a class called `App.Store`. It then instantiates this as `App.router.store`. The `store` property is also automatically set on any controllers instantiated by the router.

Answer (score 0):

Ok fixed the problem. The rails generator generated the wrong code.

This:

```
App.store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 4,
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create()
});
```

should be:

```
App.store = DS.Store.create({
  revision: 4,
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create()
});
```

Also, I might mention to anyone else who's having problems, the ember-rails generator also creates this:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

});
```

When it should be:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Object.extend({

});
```

Comment: Concerning the store, you're right, because in the first case, you declare a class instead of instantiate it. (Usually, if you call App.initialize(), Ember do the instanciation for you).
Concerning the controller, take care of not using the router, because in this case the controller must extend Ember.Controller, not only Ember.Object (due to the connectOutlet() method defined in the ControllerMixin).

Comment: The issue with `Ember.ObjectController` is discussed in https://github.com/emberjs/ember-rails/issues/67.